# There is no "get text() .contains ()" in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Below works very good in java but try to translate this to Python code (There is no  "get text() .contains ()" in selenium python ) :

```
if ((driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='payload']"))).getText().contains("report")){
           Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*       [@id='payload']")).getText().contains("<statusCode>60</statusCode>"),true);
      report=true; 
           System.out.println("Successful update executed,PASS");
      }
```

Comment: Do you mind improve the quality of your question ? By now it is not very clear. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: does any of the answers solve your issue ? In case please accept it, this way it could be shareable with others  as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for python you can use text method as follows :-

```
fetch_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='payload']").text
if "report" in fetch_text:
    # do your stuff
```

or

```
if "report" in  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='payload']").text:
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: @SharosMass Thanks... if my answer was helpful, then please support it by giving a Vote up.. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you want the `text` attribute, not the `getText()` method.

You can do this:

```
if 'report' in driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='payload']"))).text:
    # Do something
```

The `text` attribute is a string, so you can search for a particular character or substring in it.

Comment: Works like a charm, good work, thanks a lot.(had to accept other one since correct syntax and more helpful code), thanks agian.

Answer (score 0):

As other people already told you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='payload']").text
```

or if you don't get any useful value you can try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='payload']").get_attribute(your attribute that is present in the html)
```

it can be href, value, text, etc...